# Кем-то большим, чем

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли говорить: "Он не сможет стать кем-то большим, чем обычный человек".

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, здесь надо использовать "чем-то большим". Кем - это "кто ты есть", твое имя, дата рождения и прочее. Твое место в обществе - это уже не "кто", а "что".

Да, в русском языке это не столь строго, как, скажем, в английском, но все-таки такое понимание есть, и оно особо хорошо присутствует при сравнении. "Что-то большее" - это понятно, про качества. А "кто-то больший" - это уже про размеры.

> Но большинству этот человек был известен под прозвищем Врач, потому
>   что для современников прежде всего он был врачом. *Был, нужно думать,
>   чем-то большим, чем врач,* ибо то, что он совершал, выходило за пределы
>   врачебных возможностей. Предполагают, что слово врач происходит от
>   слова врати ― заговаривать. Такое родство подразумевает, что в
>   процессе лечения существенную роль играло слово.

Евгений Водолазкин. Лавр (2012) Цитата из нацкорпуса.

Автор, конечно, не самый известный авторитет в писательстве, но он еще и доктор филологических наук "по совместительству". Надо верить.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99141/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus----).

Answer (score 0):

Он и так обычный человек изначально и не перестанет им быть. Нельзя стать человеком вновь. Сравнение не совсем корректно. Да и звучит оно не очень.

Лучше так:
*Он не сможет достичь большего, чем обычные люди.*